# startactivity crashed on execute

Tags: android

I have setup an activity to be executed from a menu button. The activity is started and briefly appears and then crashes. I have added added activity to manifest file. Code poseted below. I have recently switched form Eclipse to Android Studio and still learning the changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Titles_Edit_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_titles__edit_"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is the logcat message:
08-13 11:13:45.841  15302-15302/com.example.jerry.els2015 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002

Menu trigger in MainActivity

```
public void setup(MenuItem menuItem){

Log.d("TAG", "Setting   ");

startActivity(new Intent(this,Titles_Edit_Activity.class));
```

}

XML for Tiles_Edit_Activity

```
     package com.example.jerry.els2015;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Titles_Edit_Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_titles__edit_);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is    present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_titles__edit_, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I found the issue on the activity. I setup menu and back button to finish and exit the system so bluetooth will be killed. I removed these option and was able to execute the new activity.

```
          @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
  //  finish();
  //  System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
//    finish();
 //   System.exit(0);


}
```

Comment: Would be better if you included the actual Logcat

Comment: Also, post the code of `Titles_Edit_Activity.java`

Comment: Bobby, if you figure out the issue, post your answer to the question. You're allowed to answer your own question but you should make sure you answer and accept it so others can see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

try other way for startactivity,   ex;

```
 Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Titles_Edit_Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Still crashes. I think the erorr is in the Edit_Titles_Activity but logcat is empty

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue on the activity. I setup menu and back button to finish and exit the system so bluetooth will be killed. I removed these option and was able to execute the new activity.

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
//    finish();
 //   System.exit(0);


}
```